# In my test, how can I set a model such that an Ember controller will proxy to it?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to unit test the computed properties in my `ObjectController` subclass. Using jasmine I have what I thought was a pretty simple setup:

```
describe('App.PhotoController', function() {
  var controller, model;

  beforeEach(function() {
    App.reset();

    Ember.run(function() {
      controller = testHelper.lookup('controller', 'photo');
      var properties = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
      };
      model = jasmine.createSpyObj('photo', ['get']);
      model.get.and.callFake(function(property) {
        return properties[property];
      });
      controller.set('model', model);
    });
  });

  describe('#dataURI', function() {
    it("passes through to the model", function() {
      Ember.run(function() {
        expect(controller.get('contentType')).toBe(model.get('contentType'));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

That simple pass-through test doesn't work though, the controller returns `undefined`:

> Expected undefined to be 'image/jpeg'.

I've tried both `contentType` and `model.contentType` and both are `undefined`. I added the `Ember.run` calls after seeing this error, but it shows up either way.

It works fine if I use `controller.get('model').get('contentType')`, but that's not how I'm actually getting properties in my controller functions, so that doesn't cut it. How can I set the model such that the controller will proxy to it?

Comment: Since I haven't figured anything out, I'm just looping over my fixture and calling `controller.set('model.' + attribute, attributes[attribute])`.